# Using a method from a class in another class's method python

Tags: python

I need to use a function from a class in a different class(different file) and am having issues, not sure how to accomplish this and am struggling with trying to find the right help for what i'm looking for(i may be using the wrong terms).

```
Directory Structure:
--app
  --static
    --js
  --templates
    --main_page.html
  --__init__.py
  -- MainApp.py
  --settings.py
server.py
```

server.py:

```
from gevent import monkey
from socketio.server import SocketIOServer

from app import app
monkey.patch_all()
listen_address = '0.0.0.0'
listen_port = 5000
print 'Starting Server on: http://{0}:{1}'.format(listen_address, listen_port)
SocketIOServer((listen_address, listen_port), app, resource="socket.io").serve_forever()
```

app > **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from socketio import socketio_manage
import settings
from celery import Celery
from redis import Redis
import subprocess
import requests
from socketio.namespace import BaseNamespace


def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery



app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config.from_object(settings)
celery = make_celery(app)
r_server = Redis('localhost')

@app.route('/socket.io/<path:remaining>')
def socket(remaining):
    socketio_manage(request.environ, {'/testclass': TestClass}, request)
    return 'done'


@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    return render_template('main_page.html')

class TestClass(BaseNamespace):
    def on_submit(self, data):
        #start mainapp
        import MainApp
        MainApp.MainApp()

    @celery.task(name='tasks.emitter')
    def emitter(self, string):
 #           emit to receive function in javascript... javascript pulls the 'mytext' field which contains (string)
        self.emit('receive', {'mytext': string})
    from socketio.namespace import BaseNamespace
    import MainApp
```

MainApp.py

```
import app

class MainApp(app.TestClass):

    def __init__(self):
    self.emitter(self, 'test1234')
```

How can i use self.emit from TestClass in Mainapp?   The emitter function runs self.emit that sends a string the the javascript code using websockets...  I keep getting errors such as the following ...

```
TypeError: emitter() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

OR in the case of the above...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../.../.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/.../.../.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/virtsocket.py", line 403, in _receiver_loop
    retval = pkt_ns.process_packet(pkt)
  File "/.../.../.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/namespace.py", line 155, in process_packet
    return self.process_event(packet)
  File "/.../.../.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/namespace.py", line 225, in process_event
    return self.call_method_with_acl(method_name, packet, *args)
  File "/.../.../.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/namespace.py", line 240, in call_method_with_acl
    return self.call_method(method_name, packet, *args)
  File "/.../.../.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/namespace.py", line 282, in call_method
    return method(*args)
  File "/.../.../.../.../app/__init__.py", line 50, in on_submit
    MainApp.MainApp()
  File "/.../.../.../.../app/MainApp.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.emitter(self, 'test1234')
  File "/.../.../.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 167, in <lambda>
    __call__ = lambda x, *a, **kw: x._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
  File "/.../.../.../.../app/__init__.py", line 24, in __call__
    return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/.../.../.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 420, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/.../.../.../.../app/__init__.py", line 55, in emitter
    self.emit('receive', {'mytext': string})
  File "/.../.../.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/namespace.py", line 451, in emit
    endpoint=self.ns_name)
AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'ns_name'
<Greenlet at 0x1120ad0f0: <bound method Socket._receiver_loop of <socketio.virtsocket.Socket object at 0x111c7c5d0>>> failed with AttributeError
```

Thanks!

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: What is `emitter`?  How are these classes used?

Comment: Where is your main method? What order is the code run in?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you explicitly create an instance of classA so avoid confusion.

```
class MainApp(object):
    def __init__(self,emitter):
        self.objA = ClassA()
        self.emitter = self.objA.emitter
        self.emitter('string')
```

You could also make it a class method, or a separate function if it needs shared:

```
@classmethod
@celery.task(name='tasks.emitter')
 def emitter(cls, string):
     cls.emit('receive', {'mytext': string})


class MainApp(object):
    def __init__(self,emitter):
        self.emitter = ClassA.emitter
        self.emitter('string')
```

Comment: When I do the first choice I get the following:TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Looks like you instantiate emitter to take an additional argument:

    `self.emitter(self, 'test1234')`

Just needs

    `self.emitter('test1234')`

Comment: That is correct but i can't access emit without using 'self.emit' and i can't access self without initializing it like that.  How can i access emit without doing that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue here with it being in another class. Your MainApp class inherits from TestClass, so you are perfectly correct to refer to the method via `self.emitter`.

The only problem is that you are passing `self` twice: any method call, whether inherited or not, automatically passes the `self` argument, so you just need to pass the other argument:

```
self.emitter('test1234')
```

Comment: When i do that, i get the error:   emitter() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do his backwards.

Per-condition:  You need to define *emit(someStr, someDict)* somewhere.

Your MainClass need to extend ClassA.

Assuming you have class_a.py and main_app.py

**main_app.py**

```
from class_a import ClassA

class MainApp(ClassA):
    ## now you can call any method from ClassA
    self.emitter(someArg)
```

Note:  you don't need to MainApp.MainApp(self.emitter) in ClassA because MainApp extends ClassA.

Comment: TypeError: emitter() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: emitter needs to be declared as 'def emitter(self, someArg)' then called as self.emitter(someArg).  'self' is also automatically passed as the first argument.  if you call emitter() without any arguments, python will still pass 'self' as an argument, thus breaking your code, because now you are technically passing one arg when two are needed.

Comment: makes sense but when i do that i get the following...TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
<Greenlet at 0x1093f9370: <bound method Socket._receiver_loop of <socketio.virtsocket.Socket object at 0x1093e0790>>> failed with TypeError